# Update ASP.NET Website without throwing site users away

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, web-config, application-restart

I am running ASP.NET 4.0 website (not a web project) , which is frequently modifying. Pages updates smoothly ,but some key file ,like web.config or resource files updates causes web site restarting and throws users from site, make them log in again and lose their sessions.
What are the possible ways of solving the problem.Ideal scenario is to allow existed users to work with old version and newly logged to work with new one.

Comment: 7 questions, 0 answers accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different session storage mode such as StateServer or SQLServer. Read more about the state modes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx. By default ASP.NET uses InProc session storage, which are lost whenever the application pool refreshes (such as when the web.config file is changed).

Here is another article on MSDN that walks you through how to set up SQLServer sessions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604